# How to access an open terminal session

Tags: linux, ipad, session, terminal, remote-access

I would like to know if it is possible on any OS to be able to remotely connect to a terminal prompt session which is already open as it gets quite annoying when switching to the iPad using the prompt app and not being able to connect to that already open session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the screen program? It allows you to run multiple sessions at once and connect to them from other devices/sessions.

http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Comment: No problem, also if I might recommend 'tmux' instead - it's about 100x more functional and useful than screen. It also allows for attaching and detaching sessions.